# Problem From Golan's Linear Algebra Book-Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am unable to approach the following problem from Golan's *The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Ought to Know*.

> Let $V$ be a vector space finite dimensional over a field $F$,
>   the dimension $n$ of which is even. Show that there exists an isomorphism
>   $\alpha : V \to V$ satisfying the condition that $\alpha^2(v) = −v$ for all $v \in V$.

Please give me a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A linear transformation is determined by how it acts on a basis. The number of elements in a basis is even. Take them in pairs $b_1,b_2$,...

What about sending $b_1\to b_2$ and $b_2\to -b_1$. Then, when we apply it again, we get $b_1\to b_2\to -b_1$ and $b_2\to -b_1\to -b_2$.

The same idea can be used for the rest of the pairs of elements of the basis.

Related to this idea is the following identity

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I understand. Is there any general formulation of this result ?

Comment: @user149418 Look in your own post, the statement in the gray background.

Comment: @ Pp I just wanted to know whether the above result is true if we replace $\alpha^2$ by $\alpha^k$ for some positive integer $k$?

Comment: @user149418 Then you should ask that. In the plane, you can rotate $180$ degrees by rotating twice $90$ degrees. This is what is happening in the plane spanned by the two vectors $b_1,b_2$. You can to the same but rotating $k$ times $180/k$ degrees. What would be the corresponding matrix?